# Is there a wordpress hook to catch product image update?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building a WordPress with woocommerce & WC Marketplace that allows users to be a vendor that uploads products. Now I want to know if the vendor has changed the image of their product via email.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 1 );
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
     $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
     // send email code here
}
```

but this code catches all types of updates from title to stocks, I only want to get the On-Product-Image-changed. Im also new to woocommerce so im not very familiar with this, is this possible to catch?

Comment: You need update_product_meta() where you can compare new meta with old and execute only if it's changed. If its featured image should be _thumbnail_id meta key. Double-check in your database table. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_meta_type_meta/

Comment: updated_post_meta() is the proper action my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare old vs new value for specific meta key so in this case use updated_post_meta action.

```
function product_featured_image_changed($meta_id,$object_id,$meta_key,$meta_value) {
    //First i prefer to check if its product that we are updating
    $type = get_post_type($object_id);
    if($type === 'product'):
        // Then grab current thumbnail id
        $product_featured_image_id = get_post_meta($object_id, '_thumbnail_id', true);
        //We need to compare only if we are updating '_thumbnail_id' meta key
        //$meta_value holds the new value in our case _thumbnail_id
        if($meta_key == '_thumbnail_id' && $product_featured_image_id !== $meta_value):
            //do your magic here 
            error_log('Featured image is updated');
        endif;
    endif;

}
add_action('updated_post_meta','product_featured_image_changed',99,4);
```

**Bonus** Since we know product id ($object_id) we can grab the author and from there the email of your vendor (in case he is the author) otherwise you may need to check other meta that stores who is the vendor of the product.

Comment: Glad to help :) happy coding!